# Edit other person comment (not working though)

Tags: bug

Check out the image below, this assumes I can edit someone's comment.
However, clicking it does nothing.

What does that button do there? In this specific picture it's next to Buscar's name and the *15 minutes ago*
[image]

Comment: It appears I was silly and it displays it was edited instead of that I can edit it.

Comment: Want to self answer this so others can learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is pretty easy and the question was pretty silly.

The pencil indicates that the post was edited by someone, not that I could edit it.